# Open next tab using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency, promise, puppeteer

How can I open next tab upon closing existing tab? The main thing here is I have a continuasly reloading pages in `executingFunctions` and as soon as one of the pages has proper html, puppeteer starts to interact with it, closes it and opens a new one. But what if I don't want this page to be interacted and I want to close it.

`concurrentOrders.js`

```
export default async function concurrentOrders(limit, links) {
  const executingFunctions = [];

  let currentIndex = 0;

  while (currentIndex < links.length) {
    while (executingFunctions.length < limit && currentIndex < links.length) {
      const link = links[currentIndex];
      currentIndex++;

      const promise = createBuyOrderPromise(...link).finally(() => {
        const index = executingFunctions.indexOf(promise);
        if (index !== -1) executingFunctions .splice(index, 1);
      });
      executingFunctions.push(promise);
    }

    await Promise.race(executingFunctions);
  }
}
```

`createBuyOrderPromise.js`

```
export default async function createBuyOrderPromise(link) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const page = await makeConnection();  // launch in existing browser using puppeteer (via webSocketUrl)
      await gotoMarketItemPage(page, link);
      await closeTabPage(page);     // closing tab
      resolve();
    } catch () {
      reject();
    }
  });
}
```

`gotoMarketItemPage.js`

```
export default async function gotoMarketItemPage(page) {
  try {
    await page.goto(page,
      {
        waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
        timeout: 0,
      }
    );

    const image = await page.$(itemImageSelector);

    if (image) elementFound = true;
    if (!image) await page.reload();
  }
}
```

Tried to implement puppeteer's

```
     await page.on("close", () => {
       reject();
     });
```

with passing `reject` function to `gotoMarketItemPage`

in `gotoMarketItemPage.js` but it made it work like:
if I close one of html loaded pages without the content that I need, this action stops reloding other pages in process in addition to that it stops adding up a page to the stack.

P.S. That is not full version of code for the sake of understanding. Sorry for bad explanation. Let me know if I can clarify this.

upd (full code): https://codepen.io/Alex-Powpow/pen/jORMxyK?editors=0010

Comment: Hmm, it's sort of hard to tell what the use case is, or what the specific issue is here. Can you clarify? Preferably, show a page and explain what you're trying to do on the page without worrying about your exact code at first. Then, show the whole, runnable code and explain why it doesn't achieve whatever you're trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: I can say there are a number of antipatterns here, like [using plain promises in async code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) (almost never necessary in Puppeteer), and [using timeout: 0](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#using-infinite-timeouts) which risks the script hanging forever, without a clear debug message. There's probably a simpler way to do whatever your underlying goal is.

Comment: Thx for your attention. Ok so here is almost full code [link](https://codepen.io/Alex-Powpow/pen/jORMxyK?editors=0010). Sorry for piling all the code up in one file. Not sure how to do that  correctly. Left some comments in the code

Comment: Please [edit] the post rather than posting a link. All relevant code needs to be in the question, per the [mcve] guidelines. Thanks.